# Windows phone JQuery Mobile Code not working - Blank screen

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using visual studio to develop hybrid applications to windows phone, android and iphone.

I can't get this code to work, and I don't know why. This is working good in Android but not in Windows Phone.

Basically I can not see the form. Blank appears instead.

Can someone, please, help me?

My code:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <!-- CidadaoAtivo references -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">   

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.css">-->
    <script src="scripts/JQuery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/JQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/contactos.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<div data-role="page" id="login">
        <div data-role="header" style="background-color:lightblue; color:black;">
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" style="max-width: 500px; margin:auto">
            <div style="max-width: 500px; margin:auto; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" >
                <form>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Palavra-Passe" />
                    <div  data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
                        <a  class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left" id="loginMail">Entrar com Email</a>
                        <a  class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" style="background-color:blue; color:whitesmoke; background-image:url(images/Facebook_Sticker_Icon.png); background-position:10px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:24px;">Entrar com Facebook</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="background-color:lightblue; color:black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px" >
            <div data-role="navbar" style="max-width: 500px; margin:auto">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#login" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist ui-icon-user ui-btn-icon-top">Entrar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#register" class="ui-icon-edit ui-btn-icon-top">Registar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Build Action` of each script as `Content`. To do this right click on a script file from the `Solution Explorer` and choose `Properties`. You will get `Build Action` in the Properties windows then.